# Injectivity of map from unit disc onto itself

Tags: general-topology, analysis, physics

Let $f:\bar{B}(0,1)\rightarrow \bar{B}(0,1)$ (with $\bar{B}(0,1)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2| \|x\|\le1\}$) be a continuous map so that $f\restriction_{S^1}=Id\restriction_{S^1}$, that is, $f(x)=x$ $\forall x$ with $\|x\|=1$. Using a Corollary of the No Retraction Theorem, it follows that $f$ must be surjective. I assume $f$ is not necessarily injective. However, I couldn't find any counterexample to such a non-injective $f$.

In any case, for a certain physics problem, this $f$ satisfies the above conditions and, additionally, is twice continuously differentiable and maps $(0,1)\times\{0\}$ to itself bijectively. I'd need this $f$ to be indeed injective for this problem, but I could neither prove it nor come up with a counterexample. Any ideas?

Comment: So start with the identity, represented by a framed elastic disk, then poke your fingers into the middle, one from above, one from below, and fold this over the midpoint, then flatten or project down. Or blow a bubble in the middle and then press it flat.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, is that an example to the latter case satisfying the $C^2$ and X axis bijectivity conditions? In that case, I don't follow your reasoning. Is there a chance you could give an expression for such an $f$?

Comment: Yes, that are valid points. I'm not sure that they are sufficient to refute all constructions of this kind. In non-zero holomorphic maps you get the open-mapping theorem that prevents the existence of folds (and forces the map to be the identity by the boundary condition), but here we have general real $C^2$ maps